# How to fix my output of number of runs

Tags: java

I want to print out how many times Math.random() was less that 0.5 and how many thimes it was bigger that 0.5. So I use int sum variable and increase it each time as you can see in the code:

```
package shapes;

public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i=1; i<6; i++){
    int sum1=0;
    if(Math.random()<0.5){
         System.out.println("head");
         System.out.println(Math.random());
         sum1++;
         System.out.println("sum of head"+sum1);

     }else {
         int sum2=0;
         System.out.println("tail");
         System.out.println(Math.random());
         sum2++;
         System.out.println("sum of tail"+sum2);
        }
    }

    }

            }
```

My output is :

```
tail
0.2420579681161944
sum of tail1
head
0.712979930711983
sum of head1
tail
0.28072067461911476
sum of tail1
head
0.5897197845744805
sum of head1
head
0.6735600614954825
sum of head1
```

I want the output to be like this :

```
tail
0.2420579681161944
head
0.712979930711983
tail
0.28072067461911476
head
0.5897197845744805
head
0.6735600614954825
sum of head 3 
sum of tail 2
```

I actually tried to put sum1++ and sum2++ in different places but did not worked .
thanks

Comment: put both variables outside of the loop(before the loop), aswell as the print(after the loop)

Comment: You reset `sum1` and `sum2` to 0 inside the for-loop, that's why you get that output. Stepping through the code with a debugger should quickly reveal that kind of bug.

Comment: when I put print outside the loop eclipse does not accept it

Comment: put your `sum1`and `sum2` outside above of `for` loop and  initialize with 0 and put your `SOP` statement outside below for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reset sum to 0 each time in the for loop. Move your sums variable declaration out of the loop.

```
int sum1=0;
int sum2=0; 
for (int i=1; i<6; i++){
double val = Math.random();    
if(val<0.5){
     sum1++;
 }else {
     sum2++;
    }
     System.out.println("sum of head "+sum1);
     System.out.println("sum of tail "+sum2);    
 }
```

Comment: My output is now like this :                                                                           `head
0.4261622259658855
sum of head1
head
0.3805951362559381
sum of head2
tail
0.36282685380467794
sum of tail1
tail
0.7805167757394906
sum of tail2
head
0.6868091855806376
sum of head3`

Comment: @ramialsaiad Each time you call Math.random() it gives you a new value. So you shouldn't print this value in the if/else because it will be different from the one you generated before. Instead save it into a variable and check this variable. I edited the code for you give it a look now.

Comment: thank you ,, I want to get just two outputs like this for example : `sum of head 3  sum of tail 2` ... Where should I put the print to get that output ?? I tried to put them outside the loop but it did not work

Comment: @ramialsaiad This should give you the output :)

Answer (score 0):

do as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
         int sum1=0,sum2=0;
         for (int i=1; i<6; i++){

                if(Math.random()<0.5){
                     System.out.println("head");
                     System.out.println(Math.random());
                     sum1++;
                }else { // end of if
                     System.out.println("tail");
                     System.out.println(Math.random());
                     sum2++;

                }// end of else
         }// end of for
         System.out.println("sum of head "+sum1);
         System.out.println("sum of tail "+sum2);

      }// end of main
```